# why derived class member is giving garbage value

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class base
    {
    int i;
    public:
    base()
    {
    i=10;
    cout<<"Base Constructor\n";
    }
    base(base &a)
    {
    cout<<"base Copy Constructor\n";
    a.i=i;

    }

    ~base()
    {
    cout<<"base Destructor\n";
    cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    };

    class derived:public base
    {
    int j;
    public:
    derived()
    {
    j=20;
    cout<<"derived Constructor\n";
    }
    derived(derived &a)
    {
    cout<<"derived Copy Constructor\n";
    a.j=j;
    cout<<j<<endl;
    }

    ~derived()
    {
    cout<<"derived Destructor\n";
    }

    };

    main()
    {
    base obj;
    base obj1=obj;

    derived ob;
    derived ob1=ob;

    }
```

i am a beginner in cpp i was trying to understand single inheritance how it behaves how its const,dest behaves but got a problem in the derived class derived member giving garbage value.. can somebody explain me.

Comment: [Slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) maybe?

Comment: ohh is there any way to initialize it??

Comment: Check the linked Q&A please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructors are wrong. You are copying to the source rather than destination. Try replacing:

```
base(base &a)
{
  cout<<"base Copy Constructor\n";
  a.i=i;
}
```

With:

```
base(base &a)
{
  cout<<"base Copy Constructor\n";
  i = a.i;
}
```

AND

```
derived(derived &a)
{
  cout<<"derived Copy Constructor\n";
  a.j=j;
  cout<<j<<endl;
}
```

with

```
derived(derived &a)
{
  cout<<"derived Copy Constructor\n";
  j=a.j;
  cout<<j<<endl;
}
```

Comment: or even better, use initialiser lists - since then it's impossible to get the assignment the wrong way round.

Comment: @RichardHodges - Agreed. One step at a time though...

Comment: i got that copy constructor thing but why it is giving garbage value??

Comment: You are then printing the value of j (`cout<<j<<endl;`) which has not been set.

Comment: thanks that was the problem in copy constructor.. but i was printing j. which was initialize in constructor

Comment: Copy-constructors take a reference to `const`.

Comment: @Harry oh yes, I see...

Comment: @user3207191 If you call the copy constructor your default constructor is **not** called

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructors are implemented incorrectly.

You are modifying the object being passed in, not the object you are constructing.  Try this with:

```
i=a.i;
```

and

```
j=a.j;
```

in your copy constructors, instead of the other way around.

This should (probably) do what it looks like you're trying to do, and you should be able to see why the way you are currently doing it is resulting in uninitialised member variables.

Comment: thank u i got it now.. :)